# Code runs on jsfiddle but not on website

Tags: javascript, html

This is probably a simple question and I believe it is to do with "on load", script not actually being called. When I run the code on jsfiddle it works fine, when I run it as a script file on my site it doesn't do anything.

The code in the script file goes straight into it:

```
var VELOCITY = 0.3; // Half speed is
var PARTICLES = 200;
...
..
```

Should I have a separate line in my HTML to specially call the function or is it better to wrap my javascript in something like this:

```
window.onload=function(){ /* your js here */ }
```

PS: This is not jQuery.

Comment: Could you show your current code and markup?

Comment: https://github.com/employ/employ.github.io/blob/master/js/script.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have put the script tag inside head. Since head is loaded before the body, your script tries to access elements that don't exist.

To fix this, move the script to the end of the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Hiven</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="projector">Your browser does not support the Canvas element.</canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js" ></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle adds code like `window.onload=function(){ /* your js here */ }` automatically to the `javascript`

You should have something like this in you code too, so you can prevent it from running at the wrong time.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the script tag at the bottom of the  tag like below:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="projector">Your browser does not support the Canvas element.<canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js" ><script>
<body>
```

Comment: it works for me. check from your side and let me know